# Scrolling chart window in R

Tags: r, charts, scroll

I want to  create charts from R that will be larger than the display area. ie several thousand data points (like stock charts). I want to be able to scroll left and right through the charts.  Are there any functions or packages known where this can be done?

I have various seraches here and also across the net but I can find nothing for R withough having to go and code something fairly serious myself.

Not looking for anything fancy beyond that.

Comment: You can use the RGoogleViz package and make google stock charts.

Comment: I think your best bet is to send output to a giant PDF (`pdf("outfile.pdf",width=60,height=5); ...; dev.off()` or whatever), then scroll in your PDF reader.

Comment: See [quantmod.com](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/charting/).  `zoomChart` and `zooom` may be useful

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach using the `tkexamp` function from the TeachingDemos package:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

my.x <- seq(1,10000)
my.y <- 5 + my.x/3000 + sin(my.x/1000) + rnorm(10000,0,.5)

myfun <- function(x,y,start=1, span=100, 
    xlab=deparse(substitute(x)), 
    ylab=deparse(substitute(y)),...) {
    w <- seq(start, length.out=span)
    w <- w[ w<= length(x) ]
    plot(x[w],y[w], main=paste(start,'to',max(w)), 
    ylim=range(y), xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, ... )
}


mylist <- list( start=list('slider', from=1, to=10000, init=1),
                span=list('slider', from=10, to=10000, 
                    init=100, resolution=10) )

tkexamp( myfun(my.x,my.y,type='b'), mylist )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, couple of promising ideas in there.  Thanks for the code Greg.

Answer (score 0):

A "fancy" but simple solution is using quantmod from R Shiny with Highstocks.

See [Stefan Wilhelm's "Using Highstocks in R Shiny apps"](http://stefan-wilhelm.net/using-highstocks-in-r-shiny-apps/) with [full code on Github](https://github.com/stefanwilhelm/highstock).

Get a quick preview on [how scrolling works](https://stefanwilhelm.shinyapps.io/highstock).

[Highstocks](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dark-unica) is really fancy. :-).

Comment: It'd be helpful if you supplemented the links you provide with some working example code.